# Is this a Telerik issue? Arrows not expanding selection

Tags: javascript, css, telerik

Here's the situation I'm facing. Our company website has some little arrows that are images. When you click them, they're supposed to expand the selection.

The code in question looks something like this:

```
<div class="rtTop">
    <span class="rtSp"></span>
    <span class="rtPlus"></span>
    <a title="Link To Another Page" class="rtIn" href="/differentpagelink">
        Link To Another Page
    </a>
</div>
```

I have removed the *actual* links. but what I noticed upon inspection is that the two spans contain the arrow. The problem is, when I click the arrow, it does change to the "spinning circle" (like it's working) for a split second, like it's *trying* to expand the selection. However, the arrow simply disappears, and the sub-section does not expand.

In the console, I don't get any errors that I can see. But I do get this:

> XHR finished loading: POST

What's confusing to me is that if I go **up** a level or **down** a level, it works. So if I go *into*  "Link To Another Page", the arrow functionality works as it should, and I really don't see a difference between the code at the different levels.

Another thing that's confusing is that if I click the down arrow, the span with the class rtPlus goes away -- as does the arrow.

So I go from this:

```
<div class="rtTop">
    <span class="rtSp"></span>
    <span class="rtPlus"></span>
    <a title="Link To Another Page" class="rtIn" href="/differentpagelink">
        Link To Another Page
    </a>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="rtTop">
    <span class="rtSp"></span>
    <a title="Link To Another Page" class="rtIn" href="/differentpagelink">
        Link To Another Page
    </a>
</div>
```

Thoughts? What could the problem be here? I'm not very familiar with Telerik. Anything I should try here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to come back and answer my question here. The problem was the ViewState of the page, and the ViewState of a component on the page. Once I corrected that, the functionality worked correctly.